# Exclude joined columns from a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT sa.*, d.day, TIME_FORMAT(timefrom.time, '%H:%i') AS time_from, TIME_FORMAT(timeto.time, '%H:%i') AS time_to
            FROM staff s
            INNER JOIN staff_availability sa
            ON sa.staff_id = s.staff_id 
            INNER JOIN days d 
            ON d.day_id = sa.day_id
            LEFT JOIN time_slots AS timefrom
            ON timefrom.time_slot_id = sa.time_from 
            LEFT JOIN time_slots AS timeto
            ON timeto.time_slot_id = sa.time_to
            INNER JOIN users u
            ON s.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE u.user_id = :user_id
```

I am using the alias time_from and time_to as the formatted times picked out of the time_slots table which are joined on with the staff_availability table.

The query is returning the following:

```
staff_availability_id   staff_id   day_id   time_from(join)  time_to(join)   day    time_from (alias)   time_to (alias)
```

Is there any way I can exclude the join columns from the results?

Comment: Just list the columns you want in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to select them manually.

change this

```
SELECT sa.*
```

to

```
SELECT sa.staff_availability_id ,  sa.staff_id,....--what ever you want to select and dont select those you mentioned
```

Comment: **facepalm** Thanks @echo-me I didn't even look at that on account of it being almost 4am

Answer (score 0):

select the columns as,

```
SELECT sa.staff_availability_id ,sa.staff_id,d.day, TIME_FORMAT(timefrom.time, '%H:%i') AS time_from, TIME_FORMAT(timeto.time, '%H:%i') AS time_to
            FROM staff s
            INNER JOIN staff_availability sa
            ON sa.staff_id = s.staff_id 
            INNER JOIN days d 
            ON d.day_id = sa.day_id
            LEFT JOIN time_slots AS timefrom
            ON timefrom.time_slot_id = sa.time_from 
            LEFT JOIN time_slots AS timeto
            ON timeto.time_slot_id = sa.time_to
            INNER JOIN users u
            ON s.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE u.user_id = :user_id
```